# Why is /mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/properties.html missing? Where can I copy a pre-created one (like core/...) to easy my work with?

Tags: aem, aem-6, crx

I am learning AEM 6.5 using "Build and Apply AEM elements to master components and websites!" on Udemy.

On step 43, "Lab: Create Content Root For We.Train", the following error appears - and I assured I had no mistakes in following:

> **Not Found**
>
> Cannot serve request to
> /mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/properties.html
>
> ApacheSling/2.7 (jetty/9.4.30.v20200611, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
> Server VM 1.8.0_202, Windows 10 10.0 amd64)

I have found this link which seems to be the solution, but I don't know how to apply it (I am very new):
[Show/hide properties of a page created using a template](https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/01/03/how-to-show-hide-page-properties-based-on-page-template-in-aem-6-4/)

Comment: Does the AEM server start properly? Is the error only showing when you try to create a new page or site?

Comment: @ronnyfm, it does start properly. The problem occurs when I try to access the properties of a page created using a template, in order to add some these properties to it (maybe others as well): redirect path, allowed templates

Comment: You need to share more details, please look at the error.log when you perform that action and paste it to the question, it will be more helpful to try to identify the root cause.